# Strange character appearing in subject of email sent with PHP

Tags: php

I' am sending HTML email using [PHP Mail Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), in my subject of the email I can something like this.

```
Just one more step - Confirm Your Accountâ€
```

I can't figure it out how that "**â€**" came in "**Accountâ€**", because I never put it up on the variable. Below are the codes.

**Function being called**

```
$html = template_registration($name, $email, $user_code);
sendmail($html, $email, $name, "Just one more step - Confirm Your Account‏");


function sendmail($html, $to, $name, $subject){
    require_once( site_path . "/framework/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php" );
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSendmail();
    $mail->setFrom('notifications@example.com', 'Example');
    $mail->addAddress($to, $name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->msgHTML($html);
    if ( $mail->send() ) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please help, I even don't know what to search on Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the header:

```
$headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Otherwise the email is wrongly interpreted.

Or based on your code:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; //before sending it of course
```

The `â€` probably originates from the remainder of the email but with a "wrong" encoding, the system can't make that difference (very easy).

Answer (score 3):

Try this ..You have to set header for email function.
below code tells what type of data You sent.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

Comment: This one works for me also add <br> tag for line break because that "\r\n" will not work.